# Raspberry pi : How To Run A Python File From another file

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have one python code running (A.py) when the python code reach a specific point i must run (B.py) while A.py is still running on the background

A.py

```
count = 1
while True:
    count++
    if(count%20 == 0)
         //run b
    print "A is running"
```

B.py

```
  x = 0
  while x < 10
      print "B is running"
```

Answer must be like

> A is running
>   A is running
>   ... 46 times repeat
>   A is running
>   A is running
>   A is running
>   B is running
>   B is running
>   A is running
>   B is running
>   A is running

A and b running does not have to be synchronized

Comment: which version of python does your raspberry pi have?

Comment: i use raspberry pi 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import subprocess
count = 1
while True:
    count+=1
    if(count%20 == 0):
         subprocess.Popen("python B.py")
    print ("A is running")
```

Comment: The A.py stops while B.py execute

Comment: Python doesn't support ++

Comment: i used concept on my other code it doesnt have ++.i need A to be running while the B run too

Comment: Sorry,...Edited Now

Answer (score -1):

```
if(count%20 == 0):
    execfile('B.py')
```